# How to sort search results from SCOPUS or Web of Knowledge by number of citation in a specific field?

Tags: research-process, citations

I use SCOPUS or Web of Knowledge to search papers. 
What I need to do is to sort the result in a descending order of number of citations.
SCOPUS and W_of_K both provide this feature.

But I further need to confine those citations only in a specific field.
For example, statistics paper can be cited in another statistics paper or in a medicine paper. What I'm interested in is how many times this paper is cited in another statistics paper.

Using scopus and Web of science, I can see all the papers that cited this paper and then confine to a specific field. But I have to do this for all papers one by one.
Thus I wonder if there is any search engine that can to this automatically.

Comment: This is not a question about academia, but rather a question about how to use a particular piece of software. Voted to close as off-topic.

Comment: @JeffE - I disagree; this is a question about how to use a particular *academic* software tool. If this person found it confusing, it's likely others found it confusing as well, and as such this both academia-related (hence on-topic) and broadly useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no automatic solution to this - it is an extremely time-consuming labour, sometimes performed by bibliometricians - and often only by those with access to full editions of either database (not the web-interfaces, with strict limitations to download sizes).

It is also a tricky subject, as the defionition of e.g. a statistics paper may differ from what you are actually looking at: journal categories. Papers on any topic are also published in journals not directly related hereto, there are plenty of translational and multi-disciplinary journals as well - in other words, what may appear to be a trivial task is actually very complex.